# How can I save .mp4 file into the External Storage of my phone? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, assets, mp4, android-external-storage

I have a video stored in the assets folder of my Android Project, and I am trying to take it to the External Storage of the device. I am using this Java code and the problem is that I can see the file stored in the correct directory of the phone but I can´t open it because it seems to be corrupt or something like this. I suppose I am using some wrong functions but I can´t find where. Thanks for the help.

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),"dancingblue.mp4");
                if (!f.exists())
                    try {
                        AssetManager assManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try {
                            is = assManager.open("dancingblue.mp4");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        is.read(buffer);
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        int len;
                        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                        is.close();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

Comment: Have you copied a file from Movies folder to a PC? Does it have normal size, can it be shown in video player? Have you debugged this code? What is Android version? Have you set permissions and file provider?

Comment: I can find the file in the phone and it has correct size but I can´t open it. I copied it to a PC and it can´t be shown in video player. I am working with Android 10, I have debugged the code and I set permissions. About file provider, I thought its only necessary if I want to share files from the internal storage of the app, it is not like this?  In this case I only need to take a file from assets folder and put it in External Storage of the phone. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you are right about FileProvider. So, if you copied this file and it had correct size, could you compare both files in binary mode? Can an original file from assets be played? Maybe a copy is made in text mode, I don't know, it is strange.